# oracle - query data having non-latin characters

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm not familiar oracle but have to use PHP/PLSQL to query an oracle database. These data are old and kept in a very bad way.

For example, a person's name let say `ÇİĞDEM` may be kept in several different ways like `CIGDEM` or `ÇÝÐDEM` or `ÇIĞDEM` or `CİĞDEM` etc :(

What've did so far is replacing characters that I've found using `replace` but I don't like it. It works for most of the cases but I can't just accept this. It should work for all possible combinations.

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE replace(replace(CONVERT(ADI, 'US7ASCII', 'US7ASCII'), chr(221), 'I'), 'Ü', 'U') LIKE :myvariablehere ...
```

Is there an elegant way to search this kind of data

EDIT

Database version is 10g

Comment: What character set is the database using?  Is there a reason that you aren't just using the `convert` function, i.e. `convert( adi, 'US7ASCII', <<source character set>>)`?  I'm not sure why you're calling `convert` and passing the same character set as the source and target.  Plus these characters aren't in the US7ASCII character set...

Comment: I tried all combinations of character sets US7ASCII, UTF8, I also tried passing only one character set, and several others but it never worked. Every combination has problem, like replacing non-latin characters with `?`

Comment: What character set is the database using?

Comment: `NLS_CHARACTERSET` is `TR8MSWIN1254`

Comment: What was the output when you tried `convert(adi, 'US7ASCII', 'TR8MSWIN1254')`?  If that doesn't work, what does `dump(adi)` return for the one row we're talking about?

Comment: @GuidoLeenders idea for using Soundex is reasonable, but the algorithms for Soundex and related functions that I've seen have been tuned for use with American English and thus might not work well with Turkish. Still, "Ask Google and ye shall receive" - a version of Soundex (in PHP) optimized for Turkish can be found [here](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5908-PHP-Implements-the-soundex-algorithm-for-Turkish.html). There's another sound-matching algorithm [here](https://github.com/Haran/BMDMSoundex) which is supposed to support multiple languages. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have good experiences with Knuth's soundex function which is available in oracle SQL. Or use Oracle Text as described at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/text.112/e16594/search.htm

Good luck!